# race condition plotting series with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, race-condition

I'm using D3.js to plot a grouped bar chart where data for each series (bars at position N in each group) comes from a separate server request (via d3.json()).  In the callback for each server call, I process the data and set x/y axis domains to newly calculated maxes.  However, somewhere in here I have a race condition that causes the bars not always get rendered against the correct maxes and it can take a few page reloads to get the chart show up correctly.

I don't really understand how javascript, d3, and asynchronous callbacks work together and how parallel processing really works (I'm using Chrome for dev). Any pointers to relevant literature are appreciated.

Should I abandon one request per series strategy and combine the data on the server side?  I was hoping to make this more dynamic so that in the future I could add/remove series on the fly.

Comment: For things like this it's better to use [queue.js](https://github.com/mbostock/queue), which allows you to make multiple requests and wait until all of them have come back.

Comment: Loading all series may take some time.  Another reason I went with the request-per-series approach is to allow incremental rendering.

Comment: Then you'll have to change your code to eliminate the race condition.

Comment: Right.  Hence my question and the request for useful literature.  Before I ca fix the race condition I need to understand the mechanics that are making it possible.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for in terms of literature. There's loads on the general concept that should be easy enough to find and we can't give any specific recommendations without seeing the code. In principle, fixing this should be easy though as you could simply define all your variables inside the callback and not have any shared "global" variables.

Comment: Given that axis data (variables) are global, I don't see how localizing variables will help. There will still be a race condition when publishing data into the global scope, unless processing of each series is serialized.  And that's the part I don't know how to do.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean -- eliminate the global variables. Really can't tell you more without more detail -- are you plotting separate graphs for each call? Do you merge the data? Where exactly does the race condition occur?

Comment: are you a D3.js user?

Comment: Yes? Why do you ask?

Comment: since axes are shared across all series, I can localize variables as much as I want, but all this will do is force the racing condition to the point of rendering, because axis nodes are a shared (global) resource.

Comment: So you have a single graph that you're continuously updating. In that case you can simply use a mutex, i.e. a variable you set to indicate that a callback is updating the graph and everything else respects.